# Sending anything *other* than GET using JQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, cherrypy

I'm at the beginning of my ajax learning curve.  I have a simple javascript function that uses `jQuery.ajax()` to send data to the server and receive a simple text response.  The function is correctly invoked on the server as expected and the response (which includes the value of `request.method` as seen by the server) is returned and displayed via `alert()`.

However, no matter what `type:` I specify in my `$.ajax() call`, the server always reports it has received a `GET`.

Here is my javascript (again, I do see the `alert()`, and it always reports `GET`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SendContactEntry() {

var payload = 'date='  + $('input[name=contact_date]').val() +
              '&us='   + $('input[name=contact_us]').val() +
              '&then=' + $('input[name=contact_them]').val() +
              '&note=' + encodeURIComponent($('input[name=contact_us]').val());

$.ajaxSetup({ jsonp: null, jsonpCallback: null});

$.ajax({type: 'POST',
    url: '/contact',
    data: payload,
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (response){
        alert(response);
    }
    }
);

}
</script>
```

and here is the CherryPy handler on the server:

```
class Contact:
def index(self):
    return 'You sent a %s request' % cherrypy.request.method
```

I included the call to $.ajaxSetup() because of the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263499/jquery-1-5-ajax-sending-as-get-data-on-post), but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

(jQuery and CherryPy are both latest versions, Python is 2.7)

**EDITED: More Info.**

Looking at my CherryPy console, I see that the server *is* receiving the POST.  It's returning status 301 (moved) and then immediately it receives the same request as a GET and responds with status 200.

So it looks as if CherryPy is internally redirecting the POST to my handler as a GET.  But why?

Comment: If this is up somewhere on a website, can we see the result?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254629/why-dont-django-and-cherrypy-support-http-verb-based-dispatch-natively

Comment: @sunjay03: Sorry, just on my laptop at the moment.

Comment: @rfausak: That question is different than mine.  I'm perfectly happy (for now, anyway), readying request.method to figure out what verb was sent.  My problem is that the verb is *always* `GET` even when I send `PUT` or `POST`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid I'm going to have to answer my own question.

The problem is that CherryPy redirects `/contact` to `/contact/` if `/contact` matches an internal `index()` handler.  The redirect is a `GET`.

Changing

```
url: '/contact',
```

to

```
url: '/contact/',
```

solves the problem.  I found the answer [here](http://groups.google.com/group/cherrypy-users/browse_thread/thread/176851de41b1e95e).

Comment: You can change this behavior via arguments to the trailing_slash Tool, which is on by default. See http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/refman/lib/cptools.html#cherrypy.lib.cptools.trailing_slash

Comment: Thx.  Out of genuine curiosity, do you know why this behavior is useful, why it is necessary to change the nature of the request when it happens, and why it is the default?

Comment: The behavior is useful (and is the default) because '/contact' and '/contact/' really are different URL's, and therefore identify different resources. One very practical place this is important is when you return HTML with <a href='foo'>; if the current page is '/contact' then that link will combine to make '/foo', but if the current page is '/contact/' then that link will point to '/contact/foo'. It's not necessary to change the nature of the request; lots of user-agents do that erroneously. Use 303 or 307 if you can to be sure.

Comment: Would it not be clearer to get `NOT FOUND` when I `POST` to `/contact` (at least, by default) if `/contact` is not matched rather than have that translated to a different request (`GET`) on a different resource (`/contact/`)?

Comment: Sure, you can do that. Just set tools.trailing_slash.missing = False in your config for such URL's (or the whole app). The redirection-by-default is just what a lot of app authors have come to expect working with Apache and other servers over the years.

Answer (score -1):

To send a post request to the server try this
open("POST","filename.extension",true);